# How to calculate sum of path's weight in Python

Tags: python, data-structures

How do i calculate the edge?
For example (look image): I started in the city of Bojongsoang and the destination I'm going to is Dago then the calculation result of the edge  should be 220.

[image]

```
class Graph:
      def __init__(self):
        self.graph = {}
        self.vertices_no = 0

      def insertVertex(self,vertex):
        if vertex in self.graph:
          print("Vertex in Graph")
        else:
          self.graph[vertex] = []
          self.vertices_no+=1

      def insertEdge(self,vertex1,vertex2, distance):
        if vertex1 not in self.graph:
          print("vertex not in Graph")
        elif vertex2 not in self.graph:
          print("vertex not in Graph")
        else:
          temp = [vertex2, distance]
          self.graph[vertex1].append(temp)
  
      def printGraph(self):
        for vertex in self.graph:
          for edge in self.graph[vertex]:
            print(vertex, "-> ", edge[0], " Distance: ", edge[1])
```

Comment: Do you want to calculate the distance between vertices given a list of vertices inbetween or do you want to calculate the shortest path between two vertices?

Comment: i want ti calculate distance between two vertices

Comment: The question is, are you supplying the whole path, or just the starting and ending points? Your example suggests a whole path, since there's a shorter route from Arcamanik to Dago via Ciumbuleuit, but you appear to want the longer route via Bojongsoang.

Comment: im typo i mean , "Arcamanik" to "Dago"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate the shortest distance between two vertices, have a look at Dijkstra algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm.

If you just want to calculate the distance between two vertices given a list of vertices, try something like this (not tested yet and not as clean as it could be...):

```
def calculateDistance(self, vertices):
    distance = 0
    if len(vertices) == 0 or len(vertices) == 1:
        return distance
    
    for i in range(0, len(vertices) - 1):
        changed = False
        for v in self.graph[vertices[i]]:
            if v[0] == vertices[i + 1]:
                distance += v[1]
                changed = True
                break
        if not changed:
            raise ArgumentError("vertex doesn't exist in graph")
    return distance
```

Try changing `temp` in `insertEdge` to a dictionary would make it easier, I think.